# Increments cause build failure

Tags: kotlin

```
import Foo.x

object Foo {
    var x = 5
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ++x // or x += 1
}
```

When I try to compile it I get [this error](https://pastebin.com/5xk8NHLg).

However when I replace `++x` with `x = x + 1` everything compiles just fine.

I'm quite new to the language and can't understand what's the problem. Is it an expected behavior or there is a need for a bug report?

Edit: [the bug is fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17779)

Comment: The compiler should never throw such an exception to your face. So it's a bug in the compiler, and you should report it to Kotlin (if it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: I've reported the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered a bug in the compiler. I've reported the issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17779.

You can rewrite your code as

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Foo.x++
}
```

as a workaround.